# Get standard, printable public-key string for ECDSA

Tags: openssl, elliptic-curve

I'm looking to be able to generate the same kind of public-key string that you'd get from "ssh-keygen -t ecdsa". I have an EC_KEY.

I tried using:

```
PEM_write_bio_EC_PUBKEY(bio_out, ecdsa);
```

...But I get a string that's entirely too large.

I tried this:

```
ec_group = EC_KEY_get0_group(pubkey->ecdsa);
ec_point = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(pubkey->ecdsa);

encoded = EC_POINT_point2hex(
            ec_group,
            ec_point,
            POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED,
            NULL);
```

...But obviously I want something that's base64-encoded.

Can anyone give me direction, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the public-key string is PKCS8. At the command-line, you can convert from OpenSSL ECDSA to OpenSSH *with* OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl ecparam -genkey -name prime256v1 -noout -out prime256v1.key.pem
$ openssl ec -in prime256v1.key.pem -pubout | ssh-keygen -f /dev/stdin -i -m PKCS8
read EC key
writing EC key
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBC3FrhznL2pQ/titzgnWrbznR3ve2eNEgevog/aS7SszS9Vkq0uFefavBF4M2Txc34sIQ5TPiZxYdm9uO1siXSw=
```

(I wrote about it here: https://the.randomengineer.com/2014/06/28/creating-those-neat-openssh-public-keys-and-dsa-and-ecdsa-keys-with-openssl-in-general/)

Just find a PKCS8 library for whatever language you're using. For Python, it looks like both PyCrypto and Paramiko support it, based on this Gist: https://gist.github.com/jtriley/7270594

First, this:

```
sha1digest = hashlib.sha1(k.exportKey('DER', pkcs=8)).hexdigest()
```

Where *exportKey* contains this:

```
if use_pycrypto:
    key = RSA.importKey(key_fobj, passphrase=passphrase)
else:
    key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(key_fobj,
                                           password=passphrase)
```

Answer (score 1):

@noloader reminded me that I could look in ssh-keygen.c .

This is what I found.

This is called for all key types (rsa, dsa, ecdsa):

```
key_to_blob(key, &blob, &len);
uu = xmalloc(2*len);
n = uuencode(blob, len, uu, 2*len);
if (n > 0) {
        fprintf(f, "%s %s", key_ssh_name(key), uu);
        success = 1;
}
```

Where key_to_blob() eventually leads to to_blob():

```
to_blob(const Key *key, u_char **blobp, u_int *lenp, int force_plain)
{
        Buffer b;
        int len, type;

        if (blobp != NULL)
                *blobp = NULL;
        if (lenp != NULL)
                *lenp = 0;
        if (key == NULL) {
                error("key_to_blob: key == NULL");
                return 0;
        }
        buffer_init(&b);
        type = force_plain ? key_type_plain(key->type) : key->type;
        switch (type) {
        case KEY_DSA_CERT_V00:
        case KEY_RSA_CERT_V00:
        case KEY_DSA_CERT:
        case KEY_ECDSA_CERT:
        case KEY_RSA_CERT:
        case KEY_ED25519_CERT:
                /* Use the existing blob */
                buffer_append(&b, buffer_ptr(&key->cert->certblob),
                    buffer_len(&key->cert->certblob));
```

Which eventually leads to this:

```
        buffer_clear(&k->cert->certblob);
        buffer_put_cstring(&k->cert->certblob, key_ssh_name(k));

        /* -v01 certs put nonce first */
        arc4random_buf(&nonce, sizeof(nonce));
        if (!key_cert_is_legacy(k))
                buffer_put_string(&k->cert->certblob, nonce, sizeof(nonce));

        /* XXX this substantially duplicates to_blob(); refactor */
        switch (k->type) {
        case KEY_DSA_CERT_V00:
        case KEY_DSA_CERT:
                buffer_put_bignum2(&k->cert->certblob, k->dsa->p);
                buffer_put_bignum2(&k->cert->certblob, k->dsa->q);
                buffer_put_bignum2(&k->cert->certblob, k->dsa->g);
                buffer_put_bignum2(&k->cert->certblob, k->dsa->pub_key);
                break;
#ifdef OPENSSL_HAS_ECC
        case KEY_ECDSA_CERT:
                buffer_put_cstring(&k->cert->certblob,
                    key_curve_nid_to_name(k->ecdsa_nid));
                buffer_put_ecpoint(&k->cert->certblob,
                    EC_KEY_get0_group(k->ecdsa),
                    EC_KEY_get0_public_key(k->ecdsa));
                break;
#endif
```

Which eventually leads to this (2):

```
int
buffer_put_ecpoint_ret(Buffer *buffer, const EC_GROUP *curve,
    const EC_POINT *point)
{
        u_char *buf = NULL;
        size_t len;
        BN_CTX *bnctx;
        int ret = -1;

        /* Determine length */
        if ((bnctx = BN_CTX_new()) == NULL)
                fatal("%s: BN_CTX_new failed", __func__);
        len = EC_POINT_point2oct(curve, point, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED,
            NULL, 0, bnctx);
        if (len > BUFFER_MAX_ECPOINT_LEN) {
                error("%s: giant EC point: len = %lu (max %u)",
                    __func__, (u_long)len, BUFFER_MAX_ECPOINT_LEN);
                goto out;
        }
        /* Convert */
        buf = xmalloc(len);
        if (EC_POINT_point2oct(curve, point, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED,
            buf, len, bnctx) != len) {
                error("%s: EC_POINT_point2oct length mismatch", __func__);
                goto out;
        }
        /* Append */
        buffer_put_string(buffer, buf, len);
        ret = 0;
 out:
        if (buf != NULL) {
                bzero(buf, len);
                free(buf);
        }
        BN_CTX_free(bnctx);
        return ret;
}
```

Where the actual string is built here:

```
buf = xmalloc(len);
if (EC_POINT_point2oct(curve, point, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED,
    buf, len, bnctx) != len) {
        error("%s: EC_POINT_point2oct length mismatch", __func__);
        goto out;
}
/* Append */
buffer_put_string(buffer, buf, len);
```

Where the following is used to render an "octet string" (*bnctx* should be allowed to be NULL):

```
EC_POINT_point2oct(curve, point, POINT_CONVERSION_UNCOMPRESSED, buf, len, bnctx);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking to be able to generate the same kind of public-key string that you'd get from "ssh-keygen -t ecdsa".

You can write the private key (`id_ecdsa`) with `PEM_write_ECPrivateKey`. A quick search of the sources:

```
$ grep -R PrivateKey *
...
ssh-keygen.c:           ok = PEM_write_DSAPrivateKey(stdout, k->dsa, NULL,
ssh-keygen.c:           ok = PEM_write_ECPrivateKey(stdout, k->ecdsa, NULL,
ssh-keygen.c:           ok = PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(stdout, k->rsa, NULL,
```

---

However, I don't believe OpenSSL will write the "public-key string" (`id_ecdsa.pub`) in the format string you expect:

```
$ cat id_ecdsa.pub 
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlz
dHAyNTYAAABBBEs/aVnJ16NcSOTGVNbk8ifPvPbZ0Edxd7uclo/5chC81MK7
iFb/++6parCUv0FBh47MBxV+k4rxGJ1OESe4Vxs= jwalton@debian-q500
```

That's because OpenSSL lacks the function that applies the SSH formatting. OpenSSL only deals with DER and PEM encodings, and not SSH encodings.

For completeness, there is a call to `PEM_write_EC_PUBKEY`, but PEM formatting *does not* include prologue (like `ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`) or epilogue (like email address).

Comment: Of course it will. I just needed to figure out how. There's a PEM_write_bio_EC_PUBKEY() function that I've already tried, but I'm looking for what actually goes in the authorized_keys file. Though that function does seem to render a valid public key for ECDSA, it's also curiously longer than I would've expected (probably the same difference between the two representations for any scheme). Thanks for mentioning ssh-keygen.c, though. I had stupidly skipped past that, this time.

Comment: @Dustin - I don't believe OpenSSL will write the public key in the format used by `ssh-keygen`. You will have to apply the prologue and epilogue yourself. You can see the source for the program at [ssh-keygen.c](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/OpenBSD/src/usr.bin/ssh/ssh-keygen.c).

Comment: I'm only concerned with the key, itself. I'm already familiar with the sourcecode. Thanks.

Comment: "I'm only concerned with the key" - Oh, in that case, YES. Use `PEM_write_EC_PUBKEY`.

Comment: @Dustin - my bad. I see what you mean now.